# How to re-enable hats?

Tags: support, stackexchange

How does one re-enable hats?  I accidentally clicked <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> though, in fact, I  very much enjoy them.

Answer (score 6):

I found this related answer on the gaming stackexchange:

https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/what-if-i-dont-really-hate-hats-that-much-after-all

So if you click the snowflake icon, you should get an option to re-enable your favorite head accessories.